# Exclude subpackages from Spring autowiring?

Tags: spring, autowired

Is there a simple way to exclude a package / sub-package from autowiring in Spring 3.1?

E.g., if I wanted to include a component scan with a base package of `com.example` is there a simple way to exclude `com.example.ignore`?

(Why?  I'd like to exclude some components from my integration tests)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I'm not sure you can exclude packages explicitly with an <exclude-filter>, but I bet using a regex filter would effectively get you there:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.example">
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com\.example\.ignore\..*"/>
 </context:component-scan>
```

To make it annotation-based, you'd annotate each class you wanted excluded for integration tests with something like @com.example.annotation.ExcludedFromITests. Then the component-scan would look like:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.example">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="com.example.annotation.ExcludedFromITests"/>
 </context:component-scan>
```

That's clearer because now you've documented in the source code itself that the class is not intended to be included in an application context for integration tests.

Comment: Using the exclude-filter works but I didn't have to escape "."

Comment: @Amin That's probably because "." accounts for any character including literal "."

Answer (score 66):

I am using `@ComponentScan` as follows for the same use case. This is the same  as [BenSchro10's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1403498/benschro10) XML answer but this uses annotations. Both use a filter with `type=AspectJ`

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example" },
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASPECTJ, pattern = "com.example.ignore.*"))
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's purely nostalgia, but I actually prefer XML still

Comment: it may be me, but with Spring 4.2 I have to use `FilterType.REGEX` for this approach

Comment: This was what I wanted, but I also had to use `FilterType.REGEX`.  Maybe the answer could be updated to reflect this?

Comment: Feel free to make a new answer

Comment: just a note for subpackages. If you want to exclude subpackages `"com.example.ignore"` of It should be `pattern = "com.example.ignore..*"` (one more dot before *)

Answer (score 52):

For **Spring 4** I use the following
(I am posting it as the question is 4 years old and more people use Spring 4 than Spring 3.1):

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example", 
  excludeFilters = @Filter(type=FilterType.REGEX,pattern="com\\.example\\.ignore\\..*")) 
public class RootConfig {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 19):

It seems you've done this through XML, but if you were working in new Spring best practice, your config would be in Java, and you could exclude them as so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "net.example.tool",
  excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(
    type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
    value = {JPAConfiguration.class, SecurityConfig.class})
  })
```

Comment: @JonathanW But nevertheless, a really useful answer for people coming to this page from a google search

Answer (score 12):

This works in Spring 3.0.5. So, I would think it would work in 3.1

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example">  
    <context:exclude-filter type="aspectj" expression="com.example.dontscanme.*" />  
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: Beware that it silently ignores exclusion in case aspectj isn't present on classpath.

Answer (score 7):

I think you should refactor your packages in more convenient hierarchy, so they are out of the base package.

But if you can't do this, try:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example">
    ...
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com\.example\.ignore.*"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Here you could find more examples: [Using filters to customize scanning](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-filters)

Comment: Thanks, in principle I agree with the idea of refactoring-- it was my first thought.  Unfortunately, it's not really a great option for my particular situation.

Comment: Good package design can avoid this situations, but if you can't... you can't hahaha, :)

Answer (score 4):

One thing that seems to work for me is this:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {SomeTypeInYourPackage.class}, resourcePattern = "*.class")
```

Or in XML:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" resource-pattern="*.class"/>
```

This overrides the default `resourcePattern` which is `"**/*.class"`.

This would seem like the most type-safe way to ONLY include your base package since that resourcePattern would always be the same and relative to your base package.

Answer (score 4):

Just an addition to existing answers.
If you want to exclude classes from sub-packages but not from the base package then you can change `"com.example.ignore.*` to `"com.example.ignore.*..*"` as follows

Verified this in spring-boot: 2.4.1

Taken code snippet from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30199808/2987755) answer

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example" },
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASPECTJ, pattern = "com.example.ignore.*..*"))
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [**@SpringBootApplication**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html), which according to Spring documentation does the same functionality as the following three annotations:
**@Configuration**, **@EnableAutoConfiguration** **@ComponentScan** 
in one annotation.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude= {Foo.class})
public class MySpringConfiguration {}
```

Comment: According to Javadoc, `exclude` is to _Exclude specific auto-configuration classes_, not all classes from component scan. If you try, you'll get an error "_The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes_".

Answer (score -1):

You can also include specific package and excludes them like :

**Include and exclude (both)**

```
 @SpringBootApplication
        (
                scanBasePackages = {
                        "com.package1",
                        "com.package2"
                },
                exclude = {org.springframework.boot.sample.class}
        )
```

**JUST Exclude**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude= {com.package1.class})
public class MySpringConfiguration {}
```

Comment: According to Javadoc, `exclude` is to _Exclude specific auto-configuration classes_, not all classes from component scan. If you try, you'll get an error "_The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes_".