# Spring unique bean - multiple modules

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, autowired

I'm working on Module3 which is dependent on Module1 and Module2.

Module1 has the following classes:

```
class Module1Service {
    @Autowired
    MyBean myBean;
    .....
}

@Component("module1MyBean")
class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean{

}
```

Module2 has the following classes:

```
class Module2Service {
    @Autowired
    MyBean myBean;
    .....
}

@Component("module2MyBean")
class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean{

}
```

Unfortunately, both Module1Service and Module2Service do not contain @Resource or @Qualifier.  Because of this, I get NonUniqueBeanDefinition exception when I try to bootstrap Module3.

Is there any way I can avoid this exception without making any changes to Module1 or Module2?

Comment: You could exclude them from classpath scanning and create a `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you dependend on Module1Service or Module2Service, if not , you may use the context:exclude-filter discuss  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725192/exclude-subpackages-from-spring-autowiring) .

Comment: that's a nice option, unfortunately I need both the services.

Comment: You could use an exclude-filter to exclude `Module1Service` and `Module2Service` from component scanning and manually redefine them via xml of java config. This way you can manually inject the proper instance of `MyBean` into the services. I don't think there are many other options if you can't modify the source code of module 1 & 2  ...

Comment: I think that's the only option. Do I need to exclude the services if we're anyway defining them in xml? Doesn't the xml config override annotation config? thanks

Comment: If you're overriding the bean definitions via xml config then its not necessary to exclude them from component scanning.