# Non recursive scan for packages in Spring

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

Apparently, [AnnotationConfigApplicationContext#scan()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html#scan-java.lang.String...-) scans for packages recursively.

I am not sure of it, but one of my `@Component` classes apparently loaded without being explicitly mentioned anywhere except being inside of subpackage of mentioned package.

So first question: is it true that Spring scans package recursively?

The second question, if it was true, is how to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [Spring `@Component` API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html)

> Indicates that an annotated class is a "component". Such classes are considered as **candidates for auto-detection** when using annotation-based configuration and **classpath scanning**.

About scanning and/or annotating configuration & settings check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456501/3850595), I can't explain it better

Comment: Don't see any word about recursion?

Comment: @Dims AFAIK, anotating does not use recursion, autodetect/scanning, yes.

Comment: So, the question is about scanning: is it recursive and how to control it?

Comment: for this check the link provided, but I think you cannot control recursion, just disable it

Comment: How to disable it?

Comment: as @akostajti stated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725192/exclude-subpackages-from-spring-autowiring/10725541#10725541

Answer (score 0):

About disabling sub-package scanning: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10725541/789729) answers your question (or the second most voted answer for the question).

Answer (score 0):

In your @Configuration file, it's possible to explicitly define which packages should be scanned via the @ComponentScan annotation:

e.g.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.package.first, my.package.second,
               my.package.etc")
```

Note however that all @Components within the subpackages of these packages will automatically be included. If you wish to disable this, this can be done by applying a filter to @ComponentScan

i.e.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.package", excludeFilters = 
               @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASPECTJ, 
               pattern = "my.package.*"))
```